# Apache Camel - How to use Throttle dynamically based on aggregator-output sent to JDBC?

Tags: apache-camel

I am reading messages from RabbitMQ, which get's unmarshalled (JSON -> POJO) then aggregated into multi-insert SQL statements, which are then sent on to JDBC. While I can read very fast from the RabbitMQ queue it is not possible to write fast enough to JDBC, and depending on outside factors the throughput to the database changes.

I have tried with various hardcoded throttle values, but it would be more efficient with dynamic throttling based on the speed of SQL INSERT's. I can see examples of setting a header with a throttle value, but I don't see how this can be done from later in the route.

In my logs I can see Camel reading in more and more messages and not being able to deliver fast enough.

My current route looks like the following:

```
from("spring-rabbitmq:"+rabbitExchangeSales+"?connectionFactory=#rabbitConnectionFactory&queues="+rabbitQueueSales)
                .routeId("salesRouteAgg")
                .throttle(5)
                .unmarshal(bindSalesModel)
                .to("metrics:counter:sales.in.msg")
                .aggregate(constant(true), new SalesAggregationStrategy(dbSchema, dbTableSales))
                    .completionSize(25).completionTimeout(1000).completeAllOnStop()
                .setHeader(MetricsConstants.HEADER_COUNTER_INCREMENT, simple("${header.counter}"))
                .to("jdbc:myDataSource")
                .to("metrics:counter:sales.out.msg");
```

Is there a better way to build my route to accomplish my goal ?

Any help or suggestions on the topic is highly appreciated.